# How to disable download in plone4.3

Tags: download, plone

In plone 4.3 i have write some code in plone4.3 at_download.when people access a url contain "at_download" they will be blocked. But when click the url didn't contain the "at_download" they also can download the file.

thanks.

I use documentviewer to display .doc .pdf .ppt,i just want allow them to view the file with document viewer.but can't download file from url.

Comment: Don't include the file in your site then? Or did you actually want to allow browsers to display the file *at some point*? Then you cannot block all downloads, because there is no difference between the browser displaying a file and the file being downloaded for other purposes, as far as the server is concerned. Trying to block 'downloading' is a quixotic undertaking.

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to protect from downloading?  Image?  Audio?  PDF?

Comment: The right to view and download files (same thing) is a permission on that file. Make sure the user does not have that permission, and they can't download it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this can work, but you can also try to change the `read_permission` of the "file" field on the content.

But probably this will also hide the file preview (or break the template, and in that case you must fix it).

Answer (score 0):

To make sure no one can get your files, I guess the best way is to create your own FileField and modify the `index_html` method

1. You have to create your own ATFile based content type
   Use the same portal_type if you want to use this type instead of the default plone file
2. Override the `file` Field with your own `CustomFileField`

Your FileField could look like...

```python
from plone.app.blob import field


class CustomFileField(field.FileField):

    def index_html(self, instance, REQUEST=None, RESPONSE=None,
                   no_output=False, disposition=None):
        """Docstring"""

        if self.has_permission_to_download():
            # Default behaviour
            super(CustomFileField, self).index_html(
                instance,
                REQUEST=None,
                RESPONSE=None,
                no_output=False,
                disposition=None)
        else:
            # Your code if the user does not have the permission
            raise WhatEverYouWant


       def has_permission_to_download(self):
           """Do your permission check"""

           return bool()
```

The short cut would be a monkey patch, but I do not recommend that.